# d3: DOM Elements are not really bound to data (?)

Tags: d3.js, selection

I am totally confused by this. I've looked at the example with the letters at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3808234/ where the updated elements change their position according to the position of the letter in the data set.

Now I wanted to reproduce something similar, but with div elements (`'.item's`). So far I have:

```
var displayData = function() {
    // DATA JOIN
    var items = d3.select('#data').selectAll('.item');
    items = items.data(data);
    // UPDATE
    items.transition().duration(500)
        .style('left', function(d, i) {
            return positions[i].left + "px";
        }).style('top', function(d, i) {
            return positions[i].top + "px";
        });

    // ENTER
    var div = items.enter().append('div')
        .attr('class', 'item')
        .style('left', function(d, i) {
            return positions[i].left + "px";
        }).style('top', function(d, i) {
            return positions[i].top + "px";
        })
        .style('opacity', 1e-6)
        .transition().duration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        .style('opacity', 1);

    // EXIT
    items.exit().transition().duration(500).style('opacity', 0).remove();
}
```

`positions` is a simple array of objects with pre-computed positions (they vary according to screen size) such as:

```
positions = 
[{left: 0, top: 0}, 
{left: 240, top: 0}, 
{left: 0, top: 360}, 
{left: 240, top: 360}]
```

So, given an array of four data objects `data = [{a},{b},{c},{d}]`, the above code produces a 2x2 grid of `div.item`s when called first.

Now what happens when I change the data to `data = [{b},{a}]` confuses me. Right after the data join, `items` looks as follows:

```
[Array[2]
0: div.item
1: div.item
length: 2
parentNode: div#data
__proto__: Array[0]
]
```

The `__data__` of `div.item` 0 points to object `{b}`, which is correct I assume, but then I cannot make the first and the second element swap positions because they "forgot" their old position.

Another scenario: Let's say I change the *original* data to `data = [{b},{a},{e}]`, i.e. I introduce a new element `{e}`. Then I want to *swap* the first two elements (with transition) and first remove the third element (`{c}`) and fade in the new third element, (`{e}`). Is this even possible? And what am I doing wrong/what did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d recommend reading [How Selections Work](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/).

Your example is different from the original in that you're not using a key function when binding data.  If you don't specify a key function, it will default to using the element's position (index) to figure which elements are the same (and thus should be kept for the update selection), and which should be added/removed.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data):

> If a key function is not specified, then the first datum in the specified array is assigned to the first element in the current selection, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on.

Therefore I'd recommend using a key function so that the correct elements are added, updated and removed when new data is bound.

Comment: Thanks for this better explanation (compared to my short answer). I now added the key function and it works as desired, even though I am still using the `i` for looking up positions.

Comment: I think I misunderstood how you were using positions, I'll remove that bit from the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading through some more questions and examples, I found that the problem has to do with *object constancy* (see http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/). I had to specify a certain key within the `data` function:

```
items = items.data(data, function(d){ return d.key; );
```